# To-do list with list item calculation javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I've got to make a to-do list purely made from html,css and javascript,problem is, I've barely been taught any javascript at my school and even then,I haven't touched front-end in over a year So I'm quite stumbed here ..

The idea is that there should be an input field where I can add list items to my to-do list and once they're completed,I click on them and they get transfered to a "completed " section while also counting the percentage of how many list items are completed and not completed.

I don't expect anyone to take the time to write out the code(though I would,obviously,appreciate it ),but atleast if I got some direction as to what parts of javascript I should look into,it'd be a great help as is..

```
     <html>
    <head>
    <title>Site</title>  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
 <meta charset="UTF-8"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>  
    <body>
<div class="container"> 
<form> 
<div id="myDIV" class="header"> 
<h2>To-Do</h2> 
<input type="text" id='uzd' placeholder="Užduotis"> 
<input type="button" id='todoadd' > 
</div>
 </form> 
<ul id='uzduotys'>

    </ul>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </div>
    </body>  
    </html>
```

//////javascript

```
document.getElementById("todoadd").onclick = function() {

var node = document.createElement("Li");
node.setAttribute("id","li"); 
var text = document.getElementById("uzd").value; 
var textnode =document.createTextNode(text); 
node.appendChild(textnode); 
document.getElementById("uzduotys").appendChild(node);
}
```

/////////css

```
body{ background-color: lightgrey; } .container{
    margin: 100px 300px;

}
h2{
    margin-left: 75px;
    font-size: 36px;
    color:cornflowerblue;
}
input{
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
    background: #eee;
    font-size: 25px;
    transition: 0.2s;

    /* make the list items unselectable */
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

ul{
    margin:20px;
    border-radius:15px ;
}
li{
    background-color: white;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius:7px;
    margin:10px;
}
ul li.checked {
    background: #888;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will get you visualizing.

1) create an input and enter button that will append a new line to your list
2) in your js have an onlick handler for the add button that generates the new list item with a "done" button. The done button will have a class associated with it. You are kind of on the right track there.
3) Make a DYNAMICALLY working click handler for the "done" button that clears the line in the list it is located in and add that line to your completed section.
4) have your running total that calculates when you click the add button and done button.

Comment: What is the current problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a student still I hope you take this and learn some more JS. Me as a student starting in CS I was not able to begin to find out what to do. I suggest recognizing the many js tools that there are and growing your knowledge. Try code academy for basic starting help.

```
<!-- Super basic example with no styling and no counter -->
<html>
<body>
    <label>New Item</label>
    <input type="text" id="input">
    <button id="add">Add New To Do Item</button>
    <h1>To Do</h1>
    <ul id="toDoList">
    </ul>
    <h1>Completed</h1>
    <ul id="completedList">  
    </ul>
    <script>
        //calls when the page loads
        (function() {
            document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function(){
                var newLi = document.createElement("li");
                var newDiv = document.createElement("Div");
                newDiv.innerText = document.getElementById("input").value;

                var newBtn = document.createElement("button");
                newBtn.innerText = "Done"
                newBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
                    e = e.target || e.srcElement;

                    //for some reason appending e.parentElement would not work so I had to create a brand new element
                    var newLi2 = document.createElement("li");
                    newLi2.innerText = e.parentElement.children[0].innerText;
                    document.getElementById("completedList").appendChild(newLi2);
                    e.parentElement.remove();
                })
                newLi.appendChild(newDiv);
                newLi.appendChild(newBtn);
                document.getElementById("toDoList").appendChild(newLi);
                document.getElementById("input").value = "";
            })
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```